# Free Ubuntu to Windows 8.1 Remote Desktop for Small Business

Tags: networking, 16.04

I would like to know if anyone has some recommendations for remote desktop software that would allow me to control my laptop (Ubuntu 16.04) at home/in the field to my workstation running (Windows 8.1) commercially.

Ideally it would be free, but if paying for it means better quality, I might be able to scrounge up some personal money for a license, or hopefully get my company to pay for it.

I apologize if this has been asked before.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming both machines are in the same network*

you could easily open an RDP session from your Ubuntu host to control the Microsoft machine using `remmina`.

[Remmina project page](http://www.remmina.org/)

Comment: It would be very rare for them to be on the same network unfortunately. I would mainly use it for working from home/working outside of the office(network).

Comment: This makes it more difficult but still solveable. Personally i would always prefer using VPN to connect and then again use remmina as mentioned above. If that is not an option for you, you could as well use Teamviewer which offers free & commercial solutions which might be easier to setup then my VPN & Remmina solution.

Answer (score -1):

Free would be to use a VPN to connect to your local network and then use a VNC like tightvnc or any other.

Commercially, I have used Teamviewer. It works on Linux and Windows. If you are not using it on other computers owned by clients and don't have a bunch of synced computers, you don't have to pay for it. It just gives you a windows asking you to play nice. It has great video compression too.